# how to create html DOM element like textarea or textbox in empty html div tag using knockout js code

Tags: knockout.js

I am new in knockout js and my requirement is, I have empty div tag and i have to create textarea with counter and maxlength 255 dynamically in div tag using custom binding in knockout js. when i copy and paste the div tag another textarea should be created dynamically.

if anyone knows aboout this logic please reply
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: you looking for something like this to add a textbox on click http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/FCN5p/356/  cheers

Comment: Or else you can use "ko if:" binding in your html to control the visibility of the DOM element. Here is the documentation http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Knockout custom Bindings like:

```
<div data-bind="textarea: true, maxlength:255, rows:3, cols:20" ></div>
```

Please find JS fiddle i have created textarea in div tag:
http://jsfiddle.net/shailu_snist/cp0u6p16/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot shailndra for this custome binding code. my 90 percent code has been done. now only thing remain to display textarea characters counter.

Comment: do mark it and upvote if you feel the answer is helpful.

Comment: how to make this knockout program backward compatible. how to run this program with old version knockout-2.1.0.js file